# Contextual type 'NSFastEnumeration' cannot be used with array literal

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Swift 3, would you do this?

```
let changeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(...)
let fastEnumeration = NSArray(array: [PHObjectPlaceholder])
albumChangeRequest?.addAssets(fastEnumeration)
```

or this?

```
let changeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(...)
albumChangeRequest?.addAssets([PHObjectPlaceholder] as NSFastEnumeration)
```

and what is the difference?

Answer (score 13):

As you have found (your code has some inconsistency and causes other errors, better update it), you cannot use `as`-casting to specify the type for Array literals as `NSFastEnumeration`.

You need to find a proper class which conforms to `NSFastEnumeration`, in your case it's `NSArray`.

Usually write something like this:

```
changeRequest?.addAssets([/* needs instances, not type...*/] as NSArray)
```

Comment: Comment is not a good place to describe your own issue. Better start a new thread of your own. Many people read new threads but rarely find a new comment in an old thread. As for me, I have never seen the same exception and cannot be help of you.